# Scilab error at unexisting line

Tags: scilab

I get an error on line 43 saying

```
 Undefined variable: B
```

But, the method in which it is throwing the error only has 40 lines...

Anyone has any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

Most often, this is observed when the version of your binary files (classes, jar files) and your source code version do not match. Check if you are looking at the source code of the version you are actually running.